# Tint custom UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, appdelegate

In my iPad app, I have custom `UITabBarItem` images. I set the selected and unselected icons. The selected icon is red, and the unselected icon is the outline of the red icon, but in gray. When a `UIModalPresentationSheet` is pulled up, the default behavior of the app is to tint the background gray, along with bar button items and views. However, the active tab bar item remains colored. When I use the default tab bar items, it auto tints to gray. How can I tint my custom tab bar item to match everything else in the background while the modal view is active?

Here is what I use to use my custom image:

appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOption {

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;

    UITabBarItem *home = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

    home.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"home-active.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    home.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"home-inactive.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think UI Appearance API is able to do what do you need and look for this tutorial for customization of UITabbar

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6